# removing '$' into text in R

Tags: r

i just want to remove '$' into text and i am using stringr to do this

```
a<-'r$studio'
require(stringr)
str_replace(string=a,pattern='$',replacement='')
```

It gives me following output

```
[1] 'r$studio'
```

## i just want my output looks like

```
rstudio
```

i also tried it using paste function which is also not providing me what i want

```
paste(a,sep='$')
[1] 'r$studio'
```

please provide me some help on this .

Comment: `gsub("\\$","",a)`. The `$` is a special character in `regex`: you have to escape it (through `\\ `) or enclose it in square brackets, as @akrun did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want a `stringr` solution:

```
str_replace(a, "[$]", "")
# [1] "rstudio"
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `sub`.  The `$` is a special character and it means the end of the string.  So, we should either escape it (`\\$`) or place it inside square brackets to read it as the literal character in the pattern argument and replace it by `''`.

```
sub('[$]', '', a)
#[1] "rstudio"
```